# How to get sequence number of row using Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, sql, entity

I have SQL query:

```
WITH OrderedRecs AS
(select ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY RecID) as seqNumber,* from Records where RecordGroupID=7)
SELECT * FROM OrderedRecs where RecordID=35
```

How do I get the same result using entity framework?

Comment: Do you mean `where seqNumber=35`?

Comment: No, I need record with specific ID, but with sequential number which is obtained by sorting all the records in any order

Comment: and instead of RecordID=35 may be more complicated condition

Comment: OK. So `RecordID` is a field in `Records`. The seqNumber will only number the records that satisfy `RecordGroupID=x`, so the row number will depend on that condition, is that OK?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couldn't you add SeqNumber as a derived (or discriminator) column to the base entity? [See previous example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7393788/entity-framework-code-first-creates-discriminator-column). You would have to assign it yourself.

Answer (score 1):

A pure LINQ solution would be:

```
records.Where(rec => rec.RecordGroupID == 7)
    .OrderBy(rec => rec.RecId).AsEnumerable()
    .Select((rec, i) => new { i, rec })
    .Where(anon => anon.i == 35)
    .Select(anon => anon.rec).First()
```

But than you must be happy with the fact that all records matching the first condition are fetched locally.

**Edit:**

After you comments: Propably something like:

```
IEnumerable<SortedRecord> GetSortedRecords(IQueryable<Record> records
    , Func<SortedRecord, bool> sortedRecordPredicate)
{
    return
      records.Where(rec => rec.RecordGroupID == 7)
        .OrderBy(rec => rec.RecId).AsEnumerable()
        .Select((rec, i) => new SortedRecord{ Sequence = i, Record = rec })
        .Where(sortedRecordPredicate);
}

var result = GetSortedRecords(records, rec => rec.Record.RecordID = 35);
```

Where `SortedRecord`, obviously, is a type now, which enables you to enter all kinds of conditions. (syntax not checked).

A completely different approach would be to make a view of the query within the `WITH` clause.