# How to get row index by entity key in a dynamically built query using Entity Framework

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

In a grid, I need to page to an record by its ID. That is why I need to find its index in the user-filtered and user-sorted set.

I'm working with [LINQ to Entities](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ADO.NET_Entity_Framework#LINQ_to_Entities). The query is built dynamically, based on user input.

The table contains too many (more than 10^5) records, for the following [Stack Overflow suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7892675/how-to-get-sequence-number-of-row-using-entity-framework#answer-7893229) to be any good:

```
Recs = Recs.Where( /* Filters */ );
Recs = Recs.OrderBy( /* Sort criteria */ );
Recs.AsEnumerable()
        .Select((x,index) => new {RowNumber = index, Record = x})
        .Where(x=>x.Record.ID = 35);
```

Because LINQ to Entities doesn't support `Select((entity, index) => ...)`, it would require downloading 250,000 records from the SQL server just so I could decide to show page 25,000.

Currently, my most promising idea is to transform each sort criterion into a filter. So finding the index of a person sorted by ascending height would become counting the shorter persons (sort criterion 'height ascending' => filter 'height less than' + count).

How should I approach this? Is this problem already solved? Is there any library for [.NET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Framework) that takes me even half way there?

Comment: I don't quite understand what you're asking, are you asking how to find the key value for a particular selection on a particular page?  Or are you trying to figure out the best way to retrieve a single page at a time?

Comment: Given a row id / entity key, I want to find the position of that particular row in a sorted and filtered query. Say the user decides to sort persons by name, the person set is [{id: 11, name:"Amy"}, {id: 1, name"Joe"}, {id: 2, name"Zack"}], given the id 11 I need to get index=1, id = 1 => index = 2, id = 2 => index = 3

Comment: Ok, so you have the database Id, you need to find the corresponding row in the UI, right?  What is the UI, ASP.NET, WinForms, WPF?

Comment: It's the Telerik extensions for ASP MVC, but I think it would take ages to move all the data into the UI, then try to find the index. I'm talking of millions of records.

Comment: what's wrong with your own suggestion? `recs.OrderBy(r => r.someProperty).Count(r => r.index < someIndex)`?

Comment: OK, so it sounds like what you _really_ want to do is come up with a better solution for getting a specific page of results.  Once you have a small, single page's, worth of data, the rest of it become simple.  Agreed?

Answer (score 3):

Here is a recursive function you can call to figure out the row number. If your database records are changing frequently it probably won't work, since this is calling the database multiple times narrowing down the search in half each time.

```
public static int FindRowNumber<T>(IQueryable<T> query, Expression<Func<T, bool>> search, int skip, int take)
{
  if(take < 1) return -1;
  if(take == 1) return query.Skip(skip).Take(take).Any(search) ? skip : -1;      


  int bottomSkip = skip;
  int bottomTake = take / 2;
  int topSkip = bottomTake + bottomSkip;
  int topTake = take - bottomTake;

  if(query.Skip(bottomSkip).Take(bottomTake).Any(search))
  {        
    return FindRowNumber(query, search, bottomSkip, bottomTake);
  }
  if(query.Skip(topSkip).Take(topTake).Any(search))
  {
    return FindRowNumber(query, search, topSkip, topTake);
  }

  return -1;
}
```

You call it like so:

```
var query = ... //your query with ordering and filtering
int rownumber = FindRowNumber(query, x => x.Record.ID == 35, 0, query.Count());
```

Comment: It's an interesting approach, but not by far as fast as the one I suggested in the question, which I finally implemented by (ab)using the grid filtering system. On the other hand, it's visibly better than the approach in my snippet. Thanks for the effort!

Comment: @CălinDarie - You should post your answer and accept it. I think people would benefit from it.