# How to make linq-to-sql to work with an abstract model?

Tags: c#, .net, linq-to-sql, model, abstract-class

There is a **Linq-To-Sql** model:

```
abstract class Foo
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Guid Identifier { get; set; }
    public string Data { get; set; }
}
```

There are also some descendants:

```
sealed class FooInheritor1 : Foo { }
sealed class FooInheritor2 : Foo { }
sealed class FooInheritor3 : Foo { }
```

I'd like to retrieve data from database through the **Linq-To-Sql** and also store it back.

For achiving this I would query database by casting the result to non-abstract inheritor like so:

```
var foos = dataContext.Foos.Where(someCondition).Cast<FooInheritor1>().ToArray();
```

I'd like to store some data too like so:

```
dataContext.Foos.InsertOnSubmit(new FooInheritor1());
dataContext.Foos.InsertOnSubmit(new FooInheritor2() { Data = "Hi" });
```

However, there is an exception raised on submitting:

> An exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in System.Data.Linq.dll but was not handled in user code.
>   Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

I have googled about that and found out that **Linq-to-Sql** might do what I need if I apply some hierarchy attributes to my model with specified `IsDiscriminator` column. But it told me that `Guid` typed property cannot be discriminator column.

Then I created a dummy property of type `string` on the model, marked it with that `ColumnAttribute` but there raised another error explaining me that it cannot insert the column into the database. Turns out, **Linq-to-Sql** will try to do that and will fail, unless I create that dummy column in my database table too.

In the end, how do I achive the functional I want? How do I tell it I just want the model to be abstract (because it should be) and I can handle it in the right way?

Comment: probably you can look at this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7393788/entity-framework-code-first-creates-discriminator-column

Comment: @Rex I did and it did not help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out after many attempts, there is no way to achive what I want to achive.

I did my best workaround in some particular way which is definitely not preferred for the vast audience.