# "Column not allowed here" in EF6 with TPH and Devart Oracle

Tags: c#, oracle, entity-framework-6, devart, dotconnect

When creating my DB schema with EF, Devart dotConnect generates the following SQL for my TPH class:

```
CREATE TABLE "Types" ( 
  ID NUMBER(10) NOT NULL,
  "Name" NVARCHAR2(50) NULL,
  "Discriminator" NVARCHAR2(128) DEFAULT (Undefined) NULL,
  CONSTRAINT "PK_Types" PRIMARY KEY (ID)
)
```

I always get a "ORA-00984: column not allowed here" error. Seems quite obvious, it has something to do with 'undefined' in the discriminator column declaration. Is this a bug in dotConnect or did I do something wrong with the mapping? Seems quite a simple case. There are about a dozen classes extending AbstractType, but none of them adds new columns.

My POCO class:

```
public abstract partial class AbstractType
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Mapping:

```
public class AbstractTypeMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<AbstractType>
{
    public AbstractTypeMap()
    {
        HasKey(t => t.Id);

        ToTable("Types");
        this.Property(t => t.Name).HasMaxLength(50);

        this.Property(t => t.Id).HasColumnName("ID");
        this.Property(t => t.Name).HasColumnName("Name");
    }
}
```

I'm using EF 6.1.1, dotConnect Oracle 8.4.171 on a local 11g express install.

Comment: Maybe this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7393788/entity-framework-code-first-creates-discriminator-column

Comment: My problem is not the discriminator column per se, I know what it is used for in TPH and I have nothing against its existance. When pasted into SqlDeveloper, I get an error in line 4 (discriminator declaration), whereas everything works fine when '(undefined)' is removed. So I'm quite sure the problem lies with the sql generated by dotConnect. I just don't know why it generates this code.

Comment: `default (Undefined)` is definitely wrong in Oracle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have answered you at our forum: http://forums.devart.com/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=29872#p102533.

Comment: New build of dotConnect for Oracle 8.4.215 is available for download now!
It can be downloaded from http://www.devart.com/dotconnect/oracle/download.html (trial version) or from Registered Users' Area (for users with active subscription only).

The bug with generating DDL for creating TPH tables, when the value of discriminator is not set, in the Code-First/Code-First Migrations functionality is fixed in this version.

For more information, please refer to http://forums.devart.com/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=30078.