# Code First: Avoid discriminator column and keep inheritance

Tags: c#, ef-code-first, entity-framework-6

In my project I have:

```
public class BaseEntity {
    [Key]
    public int Id {get; set; }
}
```

Then I have to define 10+ POCO classes to define the tables in my database:

```
public class MyTable : BaseEntity {
    //define properties here
}
```

Of course, because `MyTable` inherits from `BaseEntity` I get that [Discriminator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7393788/entity-framework-code-first-creates-discriminator-column) field. I want to get rid of the `Discriminator` field as I do not need the table `BaseEntity` to be created nor I need to implement some sort of inheritance into my database.

Is it possible?

Comment: I suspect I've missed the point here, but why not just ditch BaseEntity and the inheritance model?

Comment: @DavidArno I am trying to keep some sort of consistency on creating table keys, all my tables would be created with Id (int) as  primary key. Yes, I can get rid of it if there's no way around it...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A couple options:

- Make `BaseEntity` `abstract`
- Use `modelBuilder.Ignore<BaseEntity>()` in `yourDbContext.OnModelCreating`

Comment: I can confirm that •Make BaseEntity abstract worked! Haven't tried the other method maybe someone else can confirm it or not