# What is the best practice for setting/determining the concrete types in a List<interface> or List<abstractClass>?

Tags: c#, design-patterns, c#-6.0

If I have either:

`List<iCanSpeak>` or
`List<Animal>`

Where many types implement the interface `iCanSpeak` or use the abstract class `Animal` as a base class.

What is the best practice for determining/setting the concrete types that are in my actual list?

I know C# offers `.TypeOf` and I have seen examples that use an enumeration in the base class or interface to make determining easier, but what is the best practice and why?

Potentially off-topic follow-ups:

Also, what is `TypeOf` doing under the hood? Is it up casting? Why aren't the properties of the different concrete classes lost when put into a `list<abstractClass>`?

Does...
`List<AbstractClass> == List<interface>`

If the defined methods and properties are the same?

Comment: Relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2202349/251311

Comment: Can you elaborate on `What is the best practice for determining/setting the concrete types that are in my actual list` ? I'm not sure what you mean by setting the concrete types. As for determining concrete types, there could be many, which is the nature of declaring a list of an interface or abstract class. You could do something like: `var concreteTypes = myList.Where(g => g != null).GroupBy(g => g.GetType()).Select(g => g.Key)`, but I'm still struggling to understand what you're trying to do with your lists

Comment: @Rob, I'm currently working with an ORM that populates a `List<SomethingGeneric>`. Under the covers, the ORM stores all of the values in the same table, but uses a varchar column as a [discriminator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7393788/entity-framework-code-first-creates-discriminator-column). This made me wonder, under the hood, how C# "keeps track" of the different types in the list, how this effects "static typing" and if my base model should have an enum or some property that makes filtering and upcasting more performant than using `.TypeOf()`. Reading C# in depth; has me curious

Comment: @DanielBrown I'm not sure you'll find anything more performant than `TypeOf` - however, if you find you're *constantly* wanting to change `List<Base>` to `List<Concrete>`, it might indicate that you should be using Table-Per-Type rather than Table-Per-Hierarchy. The list doesn't keep track of the types inside its list. As far as it's concerned, each object is of type `Base`. However, we *always* have access to `obj.GetType()` (assuming obj is not null) - which is how you would distinguish the types at runtime. Each object knows about itself.

Comment: Thanks for the lessons, @Rob. For anyone following along, I found the following two posts about [Table-per-Type vs Table-per-Heirarchy](http://blog.devart.com/table-per-type-vs-table-per-hierarchy-inheritance.html) and [Implementing TPT w/ EF](https://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-2-table-per-type-tpt) interesting and helpful. I "think" I have a better understanding of why, how, and what's happening.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `.OfType<TSomeInterfaceOrClassOrAbstractClassOrStruct>()` extension method to select all list members that are of type iCanSpeak or inherit from it.

In your case this could be: `MyList.OfType<ICanSpeak>()`.

Some references: [DotNetPearls](https://www.dotnetperls.com/oftype) and [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360913(v=vs.110).aspx).

> Does... `List<AbstractClass> == List<interface>`
>
> If the defined methods and properties are the same?

No. They dont. Since lists are a generic class, you cant just convert them to each other. You will need a cast/convert function to do that for you.

This can be `.OfType<T>` that filters, or `.Cast<T>` that returns a new `IEnumerable` of that type, or `.Select(x => (yournewtype)x)` that also returns a `IEnumerable` of `yournewtype`. I would prefer `.Cast<T>` (this method is for converting lets say a list of `implementation` to a list of `IInterfaceThatIsImplemented`) if possible, else `.OfType<T>` if you dont need all members, but only the ones with a certain type.

Example:

```
var cars = new List<Car>();
var vehicles = cars.Cast<IVehicle>(); // works
var carsAndBicycles = new List<IVehicle>(); // think of some cars and bicycles in here
var otherCars = carsAndBicycles.OfType<Car>(); // works
var broken = carsAndBicycles.Cast<Car>(); // this breaks when carsAndBicycles doesnt only contain cars 
// this is what .OfType<T> is useful for.
```

---

To go even more in depth - what I wrote above isnt very accurate.

(Source: Jon Skeets [Edulinq Implementation/Blog](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2011/01/13/reimplementing-linq-to-objects-part-33-cast-and-oftype/))

`List<AbstractClass>` and `List<interfaceThatIsImplementedInAbstractClass>` are the same.

Not in C# kindof, the compiler doesn't allow it, but the CLR allows it.

If the checks from the compiler are circumvented, it works.

(I can not recommend using that "hack" in any sane code!)

> ```
> int[] ints = new int[10];
> // Fails with CS0030
> IEnumerable<uint> uints = (IEnumerable<uint>) ints;
>         
> // Succeeds at execution time
> IEnumerable<uint> uints = (IEnumerable<uint>)(object) ints;
> ```

Lets have some more fun:

> ```
> int[] ints = new int[10];
>         
> if (ints is IEnumerable<uint>)
> {
>     Console.WriteLine("This won’t be printed");
> }
> if (((object) ints) is IEnumerable<uint>)
> {
>     Console.WriteLine("This will be printed");
> }
> ```

Comment: This answers my "core" question; was hoping for more of a discussion around C# internals, but you deserve an "accept"

Comment: @DanielBrown a List of type IInterface is not also a list of type Implementation or the other way around. You will need a cast or conversation (`.OfType<T>` does that), so does `.Cast<T>` or a select.

Comment: @DanielBrown I've added some explanation and an example.